# Twitter sign in with android app failing with authorisation error

Tags: java, android, twitter

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<activity android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity" />


<meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="45efb6fc7ab0c3962d330203baf84301b6f82d5e" />
```

*Activity.java*

My activity class contains the following method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("Twitter req result data",requestCode+" "+resultCode+" "+data);
    // Pass the activity result to the login button.
    twitterloginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Also in the onCreate following authentication takes place:

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig("H56NrAZ6lRDgybpaKKn049w0f", "Gx057EzJ9ZQEI7D1pR9Jjo9LzTgkXWsuFr7sviVXssnuzbl2j6");
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```

And finally the code for twitter login is as follows:

```
case "Twitter" :
                        holder.appViewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.twitter_login_layout);
                        View twitterView = holder.appViewStub.inflate();
                        twitterloginButton =  (TwitterLoginButton) twitterView.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
                        twitterloginButton.setCallback(new com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback<TwitterSession>() {
                            @Override
                            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                                Log.d("twitter app","Inside twitter success");
                                // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
                                result.data.getUserId();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                                Log.getStackTraceString(exception);
                                Log.d("twitter app","Inside twitter failure");
                                // Do something on failure
                            }
                        });
                        break;
```

When I try to login with twitter using this code, the twitter app opens up and login into that app is successful but when it redirects it to my app, I get the following error message:

**com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.**

I looked into the documentation, checked on the web but no success so far. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application I created on the twitter developer's console had some problems with the permissions. I created another app on the console and re-authenticated with the help of `fabric`, everything works like a charm now.